# How to provide reference of Angularjs to script

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-mvc

I am very new to angular world. I am trying to provide reference of AngularJs to my Script. I have downloaded AngularJs from Nuget package in .NET.

When I try to drag this `angular.js` to my script then it is not allowing me to drag it into my script.

The intellisense of angularJS is not working as well.

Please guide me how to do this?

Comment: What custom script???

Comment: @Satpal, custom script is nothing but script which I am trying to create so that i can write angularjs code into that.

Comment: Try this tutorial, it is explaines from the beginning what you have to do- https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/806029/Getting-started-with-AngularJS-and-ASP-NET-MVC-Par

Comment: @thescion, I tried the code which is there on the provided link, it works. But when I type `var myApp = angular.module()` then it does not show intellisense.

Comment: Which version of visual studio you are using? intellisense is not exists in the old versions but you can add a plugin for improve it.

Comment: @thescion, I am using Visual studio 2017.